# Linear algebra two planes that never intersect.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Write the equation in normal form ($ax+by+cz=d$) of two planes which do not intersect anywhere.

What I have done:

I believe the two planes have to be parallel for them to never intersect (i cant think of any other way). But I'm not sure how to get the equations of two parallel planes.

Comment: think what parallel line is formed.what is $d$?

Comment: You can use the $yz$-plane and a shift of it, which has equations $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Two planes are paralel if they have the same normal vector. What is the normal vector of $ax+by+cy=d$?